# return output of dictionary to alphabetical order

Tags: python, dictionary, alphabetical

The following code prints out the word in the txt file and then how many instances there are of that word (e.g. a, 26) the problem is that it doesn't print it out in alphabetical order. Any help would be much appreciated

```
import re
def print_word_counts(filename):
    s=open(filename).read()
    words=re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', s)
    e=[x.lower() for x in (words)]
    e.sort()
    from collections import Counter
    dic=Counter(e)
    for key,value in dic.items():
        print (key,value)
print_word_counts('engltreaty.txt')
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You just need to sort the items.  The builtin `sorted` should work wonderfully:

```
for key,value in sorted(dic.items()):
    ...
```

If you drop the `e.sort()` line, then this should run in approximately the same amount of time.  The reason that it doesn't work is because dictionaries are based on `hash` tables which store items in order of their hash values (with some more complicated stuff when hash collisions occur).  Since the hashing function is never specified anywhere, it means that you can't count on a dictionary keeping any order that you try to give it and that the order is implementation and version dependent.  For other simple cases, the `collections` module has an `OrderedDict` subclass which does keep insertion order.  however, that won't really help you here.

Comment: Just this: sorted(dic.items()) worked for me, thanks.

Comment: what i dont just want the keys, but the whole key value pairs sorted alphabetically?

Comment: @AkinHwan -- I'm not sure I understand the question... The `items()` is an iterable of 2-tuples (key-value pairs).  The 2-tuples will sort lexicographically.  This will sort on keys first (and in the event of a tie, then the value will be compared).  Of course, since this is a dict, our keys will be unique ... I'm not sure what you mean by "the whole key-value pairs sorted alphabetically",  Maybe try `sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[0] + x[1])`?

Answer (score 0):

Note `Counter` is a subclass of `dict` so sorting before you add to `Counter`:

```
e.sort()
dic=Counter(e)
```

won't achieve order.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def print_word_counts(filename):
    c = Counter()
    with open(filename) as f: # with block closes file at the end of the block
        for line in f: # go line by line, don't load it all into mem at once
            c.update(w.lower() for w in re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', line))

    for k, v in sorted(c.items()): # sorts
        print k, v

print_word_counts('engltreaty.txt')
```